# Transmission line and flag pole

Tags: electromagnetism

I have noticed this phenomenon and I was looking for a way to calculate/quantify it.

An overhead power transmission line crosses an open field on lattice towers (so I am assuming several kV). About 100m away from it (lateral ground distance) is a round hollow metal flag pole about 10m tall and about 5cm diameter. When touching the flag pole, one can feel/hear electric discharge from the pole to the finger. How can one quantify the potential between the finger and the ground when touching the pole?

Is this caused by induction on the loop of the pole (which seemed small with B at only a few uT) or is this caused by the electric charges moving from the electric field created within the rod of the flag pole?

Thanks!

Comment: I suspect you're sensing physical vibrations in the flagpole, not a current, although there is likely a small current present.

Comment: Thanks! I do get zapped with an audible spark noise when touching it.